# Ajax post method not returning value from function

Tags: ajax, function, post

My Ajax call works successfully inside my function but I am unable to return the the result outside the function. Does this have something to do with Ajax or how I am trying to return the result from the function?

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Vote </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="vote">
        <td id="upvote">1</td>
        <td id="downvote">-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="newvote"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var myvote = allFunction4(); //returns undefined
    alert(myvote); 

})

function allFunction4() {
    $('.vote').children().click(function() {
        var vote = $(this).text();
        var timestamp = 1369705456; //value I know exits in db
        $.post('forumvote.php', {'timestamp': timestamp, 'vote': vote}, function(result,   success) {
            var newvotes = result;
            alert(newvotes); //this works
            return newvotes;
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because I think you are returning value from a function within the $.post... the return statement is NOT returning from the allfunction4().

You may want to re-refer the JQuery documentation on JQuery.post at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php", function() {
alert("success");
})
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
// perform other work here ...
// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function(){ alert("second finished"); });
```

Comment: I looked at the documentation again, but I'm just not seeing the answer, so I switched to $.ajax and set async:false, and that seems to do what I want. Not sure if that is the best solution but it works for now while I do further research. Thanks.

Comment: @user2232681 glad .ajax worked for you. As I was focusing on your use of .post and issues you were facing, it didn't even occur to me to suggest using .ajax - in theory they both yield same results, in practice use of .ajax gives you a little bit more control over it. Following discussion at JQuery might help you understand differences a little better - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-should-i-use-post-vs-ajax